# Online documentation tool with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to develop a web application for documentation..

The tool is functional.. Please review the code & help me with performance tuning & simplifying the JavaScript part..

Any suggestions or comment most welcome. Thanks in advance!

**Note:** Please type something on the `<textarea>` to see the live preview

```js
$(function() {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

  $('#doc_content').on('input', function() {
    var doc = this.value
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/__hj/g, '<pre><code>')
      .replace(/hj__/g, '<br/></code></pre>')
      .replace(/__tl\s?/g, '<h3>')
      .replace(/\s?tl__/g, '</h3>')
      .replace(/__st\s?/g, '<h4>')
      .replace(/\s?st__/g, '</h4>')
      .replace(/__(o|u)l[^]*?(o|u)l__/g, m => m.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "</li><li>"))
      .replace(/__ol\s?/g, '<ol><li>')
      .replace(/\s?ol__/g, '</li></ol>')
      .replace(/__ul\s?/g, '<ul><li>')
      .replace(/\s?ul__/g, '</li></ul>');

    $('#doc_preview').html(doc);

    hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
    hljs.initHighlighting();
  })
});
```

```css
#doc_content {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  resize: vertical;
  width: 99%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
}

#doc_preview {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
  color: #242729;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.35;
}

#doc_preview .hljs {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#doc_preview * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#doc_preview h3 {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
}

#doc_preview h4 {
  margin-bottom: -24px;
  font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
}

#doc_preview ul,
#doc_preview ol {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#doc_preview li {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#doc_preview li:last {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.18.1/styles/atom-one-dark.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Neuton:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.18.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <textarea id="doc_content">
  __tl Some good title ! tl__

You can see a live preview as you type...

__hj
$(function(){
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

    $('#doc_content').keyup(function(){
        var doc = this.value
            .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
            .replace(/>/g, "&gt;");

        $('#doc_preview').html(doc);

        hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
        hljs.initHighlighting();
    })
});
hj__

__tl This is a sub title tl__

It's a great site to get answers for your programming queries !!

Here is a Ordered list:
__ol Login or Signup
Post your query
Check the answers. If you need any clarification, post a comment 
Accept answer ol__
Here is an Unordered list: 
__ul This is list item 1
This is item 2 ul__

A long passage will loook like below:

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </textarea>
  <div id="doc_preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pugazh Some more details in the question body would be also helpful.

Comment: Yes from [The Help center page _How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: "a web application for documentation" This tells us very little. What's the goal of you program?

Comment: For anyone voting to close this question: run the code snippet. Start typing. The code is an editor. While it could certainly use more explanation than that, it's perfectly reviewable as-is.